# ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key ~ Google reCAPTCHA ~ GitLab CI

Tags: firebase, webpack, environment-variables, recaptcha, gitlab-ci

I'm having issues when deploying my application through GitLab CI with reCAPTCHA API key to Firebase. Whenever I'll deploy the application from terminal using `firebase deploy` it works perfectly fine. However, when will deploy it after passing GitLab pipelines then it in the application I can see the following error `ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key`. I checked many times if the environmental variable (name and API key) is the same compared to `.env` file which locally stores all my environmental variables. Don't know if it matters, but I'm using Webpack with [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) package for it.

I'm getting the environmental variables using such way `siteKey: String(process.env.RECAPTCHA_API_KEY)`. Without `String` I even can't see the reCAPTCHA element. Using reCAPTCHA v2.

Comment: new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.RECAPTCHA_API_KEY': '"' + process.env.RECAPTCHA_API_KEY + '"',

Comment: Did you tried adding this in your webpack,config,js file?
new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 
    'process.env.RECAPTCHA_API_KEY': '"' + process.env.RECAPTCHA_API_KEY + '"', 
...